# Implement Advanced Search Parameters in Spring Boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I would like to implement advanced search functionality in my Spring Boot application.

Since I want to follow good practices, I did some research on this topic, but ended up without any concrete example or solution.

I've read about a method using `Predicate`, but did not find any suitable explanations.

So, I want to my filters to be optional and also to contain arrays of values to query (e.g. My entity `User` has a list of `Subject` entities in it, so I want to send an array of `Subject ids`)

One of the things that came to my mind is sending a special *DTO*, including all possible filters, and than, with good old if statements do the rest of the work. (Checking if filter is not null, then query it etc.)

As far as I know, this method would not be very flexible, nor it would belong to the **best practices** category.

Another option, sending a bunch of parameters in the url, is not so grateful either. Or is it?

How to implement DAO layer is not a problem, for now, I am only interested in my options when it comes to sending filters to my `REST Controllers`. Client sending the request is written with `ReactJS`.

Thank You for Your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement it on a Rest api , it better not to use Dto for getting list of items,the best way to get list by filters is to use different request params on your endpoints and check them if they're null or have values in your application